# .NET Custom search on combobox auto-complete

Tags: .net, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combobox control in my form. I have enabled autocomplete feature in suggest mode. By default, the control suggests all the strings which ***starts with*** the text the user have introduced. Is there any way to change this behavior to make the control suggest all the strings which ***contains*** current text?

I'm trying to avoid creating a custom control to make that.

Comment: Did you manage to achive that somehow? I'm having the same requirement.

Comment: Hi, Ive implemented a custom control to handle this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so; documentation only mentions matching based on prefixes, and from my experience with the ComboBox I don't believe it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING is not introduced until Windows Vista. Supporting the behavior in Windows Forms would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the combobox OnTextChanged event and do something like this:

```
foreach (string item in combobox.items)
    string.Contains(items);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tryied that. I captured TextChenged event to rebuild the AutoCompleteStringCollection but it remains suggesting only the items widh starts by the current text.